# Should drivers be installed manually or via external applications?

Tags: installation, drivers, security, computer-building

I've recently built my first computer and found the task of getting the drivers to be extremely tedious, time consuming and sometimes a little tricky.

In some cases there are multiple options to choose from. The offer of the latest driver can also come with the risk of being a Beta version. I've also found that some components (like my GPU) had optional drivers that may apply to applications I might never use.

I recently discovered that there are downloadable applications that can detect and fetch the necessary drivers for you even update them automatically. I understand that this may be seen as a lazy approach but for a first-time builder like myself it seems like a safer bet, given that I don't yet know what drivers to choose from.

So should applications this be used or are they best avoided? I have no doubt that some of these applications may be harmful and open me up to risks from viruses. Am I better off trawling the internet for answers about the best drivers for each component for my computer?

For anyone wondering the application I'm currently considering is 'SlimDrivers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing drivers is the tedious part, but the nature of the beast. If it is freeware you are speaking of using that comes at a cost too, in the way of hitch-hiking crapware that comes along with it.

I just looked over the reviews on Cnet, they are mixed for Slimware. IMO, I would do it manually, even if it is not the latest version. I only have Win7 and it automatically updates the drivers when I choose "optional updates".

With time on hand though, I search for the latest online, and download everything to a flash drive, in a folder with the computer name I give it, and name each driver that is easy for me to pick and choose which one to install, rather than the name they are called on the website I get them from. Some of the naming conventions are totally non-descriptive.